# how to create line breaks using php

Tags: php, line-breaks

I am not very good with PHP but am trying to add line breaks to some woocommerce text. I have tried:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
echo nl2br(   $new_str = $str .  " 

You will shortly receive a confirmation email. We will email you again once your order has been dispatched.

With best wishes – and happy styling,

Wendy & Emma x
");
    return $new_str;
}
```

This gives me the line breaks but also shows the text a 2nd time without line breaks:

> You will shortly receive a confirmation email. We will email you again once your order has been dispatched.

> With best wishes – and happy styling,

> Wendy & Emma x
> Thank you. Your order has been received. You will shortly receive a confirmation email. We will email you again once your order has been dispatched. With best wishes – and happy styling, Wendy & Emma x

How do I get it to show the text once only with line breaks?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `echo` when setting the value and only displaying the value with line breaks (using `nl2br()`).

It's the `echo` which is displaying the value the first time.  The second time is the returned value from the function.

Instead you just need to return the new value...

```
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    return nl2br( $str .  " 

You will shortly receive a confirmation email. We will email you again once your order has been dispatched.

With best wishes – and happy styling,

Wendy & Emma x
");
}
```